# x86 assembly strange error

Tags: assembly, x86

I am using windows version code blocks 12.11, with integrated 32bit mingw gcc 4.7.1, Windows 8.1 64bit.

in the main.c, code:

```
__asm volatile
(
    "mov ebx, esp\n\t"
    "mov eax, fs : [ebx]\n\t"
    "mov %0, eax"
    : "=m"(reg)
);
```

in the api.S, code:

```
.text
func:
    enter 0, 0

    mov ebx, esp
    mov eax, fs : [ebx]

    leave
    ret
```

compile option: `-masm=intel -Wa,-msyntax=intel,-mnaked-reg`

The main.c compile ok, but the api.S meets an assembler error: invalid use of register.

As I know, the inline assembly code is sent to gas directly. I don't know why the same instructions(`mov eax, fs : [ebx]`) have different result.

Now we only dissuss syntax issue. I know the runing result may be segmnentation fault.

Comment: What's this code supposed to do? Why do you need to use `fs`?

Comment: The gcc is 4.7.1, 32bit. And I use gcc to generate normal 32bit app.

Comment: If I comment the line "mov eax, fs : [ebx]", compile success.

Comment: The full compile message is :
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall  -g  -std=c99 -masm=intel -Wa,-msyntax=intel,-mnaked-reg    -c D:\CB\win\api.S -o obj\Debug\api.o
D:\CB\win\api.S: Assembler messages:
D:\CB\win\api.S:26: Error: junk `:[ebx]' after expression

Comment: If I change fs to ds, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved.

If I add ".intel_syntax noprefix" in the file api.S. Compile success!

---

But I don't know why the option '-Wa,-msyntax=intel,-mnaked-reg' not work...